# Finding Paths Within SVGs

Tags: svg, path, css-selectors, find

I have a raster image marking up an SVG that I have attached...
[Markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWZtt.jpg)

Here is the SVG in html...
[SVG code](https://codepen.io/mikes1025/pen/bGKeGma)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="6.4in" height="3.6in" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 6400 3600"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xodm="http://www.corel.com/coreldraw/odm/2003">
```

How do I find the path as highlighted in the markup in order to ID it? Thank you.

Comment: give the path an id is probably the most straightforward. We don't do discussion questions here though.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, I'm not sure how discussion questions are handled. I understand that you mean to mark path with an ID within it's SVG code, but how would you find the path to begin with? If someone gave you an SVG of a texture image of tree bark and marked a few vectors they want ID'd in red- how would you find those paths in SVG code? I understand this could be a long answer but a shorthand answer would work, I can do my own research given a proper direction. Thanks

Comment: Break your question up into single questions, with the code fragments you tried.
And add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: In the first example you linked, it shows adding an id to an path and using getElementById to get that path in the javascript. Is that enough to accomplish your goal? If not, what exactly to you need to do that can't be done that way?

Comment: @aptriangle thank you for responding. I understanding adding an id to path but I'd like to know how to find the path I want ID'd to begin with. If you were working with an SVG comprising 1000 vectors provided by an employer then said employer mailed you a printed markup of that image with vectors he wants you to find, select, and add listeners to... how would you begin finding those marked vectors? Thank you

Comment: I'd find a program that allowed me click on paths and add ids graphically. For a computer program to automatically find what you want, you first need to be able to describe what you want in a measurable way. Converting a printed markup to something the computer understands would be a complex, and inaccurate, task. Unless there's something logically distinct about the paths you need to collect, like length or color or something else, it will be a manual process.

Comment: Thank you @aptriangle. That's a very straightforward answer. I will expand and find an answer tailored more for me, the easy way or the hard way.

Comment: You can also use your browser's **dev tools and inspect the svg**. In your case,  the path you're searching is the last element in the `<g>`  stack - probably it should be the first, since you'll need a fill to give it a pointer area.

Comment: thank you @herrstrietzel that's a good idea, I'll take my question to a forum from the software I created the SVG with, CorelDraw. I believe I will eventually have to learn to read coordinate data.

Comment: Just an update: CorelDraw(the software I create SVGs with) exports style data, I use that to my advantage by assigning spot colors to designated paths in the design software then find the paths by finding the HTML class assigned to them. It's a pretty simple process and as @aptriangle foretold, a manual one.